# indexOf don't work for me. Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, indexof, searchbar

so for me the indexOf Function to handle with strings does not work like it should. I get a list of objects with the type of "Betreiber". like you can see in the screenshot I get the data correctly. But i can't filter with indexOf and I don't get why?

```
   getFiltList(searchquery: string): Observable<Betreiber[]>{
    return Observable.create( observable => {
        this.fbProvider.getListObs().subscribe( allItems => {
            console.log("Query: " + searchquery);
            console.log(allItems);

            let filteredList = allItems.filter(b => b.name.indexOf(searchquery) > -1); <!-- stop doing work here.. !-->

            console.log(filteredList);
            observable.next(filteredList);
            observable.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

[Screenshot 1: Console log with query input="Test123"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS3em.png)

if I change it into `let filteredList = allItems.filter(b => b.name === searchquery);`

the search for the exact name of the object with type 'Betreiber' works 
[Console log with query: Test123 after line change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFq1l.png)

Hope you can help out.. Also tried with `.toLowerCase()` for the searchquery and for the name of course :)

Comment: it'll be easier to help if you can create a working piece of code with some data you are working with. Use [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/) or [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your last item of data array ,`{anschrift:{...},bankverbindung:{...},id:..., name2:...}`, does not have property `name` but `name2`.

So, `b.name.indexOf(searchquery)` cannot be executed and invokes runtime error because `b.name` is `undefined`, While, `b.name === searchquery` can be executed.